# calling virtual function by vptr

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I was recently reading about virtual functions and inheritance in C++, and ended up with the vptr and VTABLE.

My question is related to calling the methods of derived objects with means of vprt.

I explain, below is my code :

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


    class base
    {
    public:
        void fun_1() { cout << "base-1\n"; }
        virtual void fun_2() { cout << "base-2\n"; }
        virtual void fun_3() { cout << "base-3\n"; }
        virtual void fun_4() { cout << "base-4\n"; }
    };

    class derived : public base
    {
    public:
        void fun_1() { cout << "derived-1\n"; }
        void fun_2() { cout << "derived-2\n"; } 
        void fun_4() { cout << "derived-4\n"; }
    };

    int main()
    {
        base *p;
        derived obj1;
        p = &obj1;

        void(*firstfunc)() = (void(*)(void))(*(int*)*(int*)p);
        firstfunc();
    }
```

the result is :

> derived-2

Ok, till now, the operations done with `(void(*)(void))(*(int*)*(int*)p)` sttill fuzzy in my mind, butt how could I do to call the second function ?

Thx

Comment: Where did you get the idea to write `void(*firstfunc)() = (void(*)(void))(*(int*)*(int*)p);` and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Vtables and vptrs are internal implementation details, this code is depending on undefined behavior.

Comment: No need (and actually no guaranteed support) to access any `vtable`; just do `p->fun_1()` or `p->fun_2()`; the language handles dynamic binding then for you.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you're way, way off track as far as learning C++, inheritance and polymorphism. @scohe001's question is on point - where are you getting this and what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @scohe001: I am with you and they are internals. but I read that all is done by the magic of deferencing.

Comment: `*(void(*)(void))(*(int*)*(int*)p) sttill fuzzy in my mind*` -- It should be -- it's probably fuzzy in most programmer's minds.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Yes, that's how it works internally, but you can't do it portably in your own code.

Comment: @Barmar : I saw tthat here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: If you want to call virtual functions dynamically through a variable, use `void(base::*firstfunc)() = p->fun_1;`

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd From that page: **Many compilers place the virtual table pointer as the last member of the object; other compilers place it as the first**

Comment: If you think you need to care about the internals of this stuff then stop. You're doing it wrong. While it may be useful to know how things are implemented "under the hood", you as a *user* of the language should never need to know nor care.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Agree and stopped by the way :) There is nor harm with curiosity when it is just for learning (not to use in real life). :D

Comment: Perhaps this question could be clarified.  Are you asking how to **manually** find a vtable pointer and index into it?

Comment: You know that virtual member functions have a this parameter, right?

Answer (score 1):

> how could I do to call the second function ?

You would call it like this:

```
p->fun_2();
```

prints:

```
derived-2
```

Virtual tables and virtual function pointers are implementation details of your compiler. In general you should not care about such implementation details, because if you do you write non-portable code. Actually I am not even sure if your code has undefined behaviour or not, if it does then even a compiler that does place the vpointer at the place you expect could print garbage. Anyhow, dont do it, unless you need to, which is actually never ;).

As a sidenote, function pointers loose lots of their scariness if you use aliases, eg

```
using base_mem_fun = void (base::*)();
base_mem_fun first_base = &base::fun_1;
(p->*first_base)();
```

prints:

```
base-1
```